# Hiding status bar: effect on bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I'm working through the Big Nerd Ranch's iOS Programming book (3rd edition), and there's one particular example that involves a full screen image embedded in a full screen UIScrollView.  Both are created as follows:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
CGRect screenRect=[[self window] bounds];
UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
view=[[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
```

We're asked to make the status bar disappear using the following line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Everything works fine, but what I don't understand is this:  why are the window's bounds the same regardless of whether or not the status bar is there?  They are always (0,0,320,568), but I would have expected the height to shrink if I hid the status bar.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` always returns the **frame of the device** which will be the same for the device always irrespective of weather your app shows or hides the status bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So does that mean that the `scrollView` and `view` actually have content outside of the viewable screen when there is a status bar present?

Comment: @Rogare Yes, you are correct if you set the frames of scrollview and view to be that of `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`. But usually, when you plan to display the status bar, if you want both your view and scrollview to cover the entire screen, you will set a height that is lesser by the height of the status bar.

Comment: OK, I guess they just avoided that in the book for simplicity.  Thanks!